# Hive on Tez doesn't work on Hue (Error: Client Version = unknown) after upgrading HDP 2.2 to 2.3

Tags: hadoop, hive, upgrade, hue, tez

I have upgraded HortonWorks from 2.2 to 2.3 for our Hadoop cluster and made all the required changes to Hue (given in HortonWorks documentation) but hue client has following issues when accessing Tez on Hive browser whereas Tez on Hive CLI works perfectly alright. Earlier (HDP 2.2), Tez was compatible with Hue but is there a problem with Hue client with Tez on HDP 2.3?

**Issue 1:** After upgrading HDP 2.2 to 2.3, Tez still looks for HDP 2.2 libs files in HDFS and local location.
HDP 2.2 location:

> **HDFS:** /hdp/apps/2.2.9.0-3393
>
> **Local Files:** /usr/hdp/2.2.9.0-3393

**Temporary Solution to Issue 1:** Moved 2.3 supporting files to 2.2

HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -cp /hdp/apps/2.3.2.0-2950/tez/tez.tar.gz /hdp/apps/2.2.9.0-3393/tez/
```

Local Files:

```
cp /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hive/lib/hive-exec-0.14.0.2.2.9.0-3393.jar /usr/hdp/2.2.9.0-3393/hive/lib/
cp /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop/lib/jersey*.jar /usr/hdp/2.2.9.0-3393/hadoop/lib/
cp /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop-yarn/lib/jersey*.jar /usr/hdp/2.2.9.0-3393/hadoop-yarn/lib/
cp /usr/hdp/2.3.2.0-2950/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/jersey*.jar /usr/hdp/2.2.9.0-3393/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/
```

**Technically, Tez must look for "/usr/hdp/current" directory which is 2.3.2.0-2950.**

**Issue 2:** Running Hive on Tez through Hue gives following error:

**Error:**

```
Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
ERROR : Failed to execute tez graph.
org.apache.tez.dag.api.SessionNotRunning: TezSession has already shutdown. No cluster diagnostics found.
```

Through some research it is found that when Tez execution is not required to run a Hive query, Hue client version matches with AM version whereas any query which needs tez execution Hue client version shown as unknown.

- Client version and AM version match when Tez execution is not required:

  Created DAGAppMaster for application    appattempt_1470224940790_0082_000001, versionInfo=[    component=tez-dag, version=0.7.0.2.3.2.0-2950,    revision=4900a9cea70487666ace4c9e490d4d8fc1fee96f,    SCM-URL=scm:git:https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/tez.git,    buildTime=20150930-1859 ]    [INFO] [main] |app.DAGAppMaster|: Comparing client version with AM version, clientVersion=0.7.0.2.3.2.0-2950,    AMVersion=0.7.0.2.3.2.0-2950
- Client version and AM version doesn't match when Tez execution is enabled:

  Created DAGAppMaster for application appattempt_1470224940790_0092_000001, versionInfo=[ component=tez-dag, version=0.7.0.2.3.2.0-2950, revision=4900a9cea70487666ace4c9e490d4d8fc1fee96f, SCM-URL=scm:git:https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/tez.git, buildTime=20150930-1859 ]
  Comparing client version with AM version, clientVersion=Unknown, AMVersion=0.7.0.2.3.2.0-2950
  [ERROR] [main] |app.DAGAppMaster|: Incompatible versions found, clientVersion=Unknown, AMVersion=0.7.0.2.3.2.0-2950

Can anyone help on how to find a solution for incompatible version error when Tez is enabled through Hue on HDP 2.3.

Comment: About issue 1: any chance that you have one of the conf files used by HiveServer2 (i.e. `hive-site.xml` or `tez-site.xml`) that was not properly upgraded, and property `tez.lib.uris` still uses the HDFS path for the previous version?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thank you for the prompt response. I have checked the **tez-site.xml** properties and it is pointing towards the new version of HDP. `<name>tez.lib.uris</name>
      <value>hdfs:///hdp/apps/${hdp.version}/tez/tez.tar.gz</value>`. I think these issues are specific to Hue because if there could be problem in **tez or hive.site.xml** files then running Tez through CLI would have given the same error.

Comment: Huh - that `${hdp.version}` thing is specific to HortonWorks and is a known source of problems with 3rd-party tools, such as Spark builds downloaded from the Apache site. And Hue is a Cloudera creature, that HortonWorks reluctantly tolerates (but only outdated versions). So I'm not sure HDP does a good work of updating `hdp.version` property in the Hue service config.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter : Is there any fix?